# How can I guess numbers of phases and angles in unitary matrix parametrization?

Tags: group-theory

Suppose unitary matrix $A\in U(3)$. It can be parametrized with 3 angles and 6 phases. Three angles belong to parametrization of $SO(3)$ subgroup of $U(3)$ group. An example is CKM matrix before making quark fields rotations (my question arises because of this matrix).

My question is, why all the other parameters are phases? Is there some argument (for example, other subgroups of $U(3)$ in subgroups expanasion don't have pure real representation etc), which help me to guess that there are 6 phases (not $n$ angles and $6-n$ phases)? I understand that there is direct way to ensure this --- by imposing unitarity condition explicitly.

Comment: *U(3)* has *O(3)* as a subgroup, so, then at least 3 of its 9 parameters are angles. 1 is the singlet you take out. The remaining 5 are likely to be phases, as there appears no way to align the imaginary components so they are not.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: I'm not sure: it is a basic generation physics mathematical fact... Good texts should cover it... In any case, for 17 generations, the *O(17)* subgroup dictates 17x16/2 angles, and the rest is phases....

Comment: This is a very good question. The answer is that the number of angles is equal to half the dimension of the flag manifold $SU(3)/(U(1))^2$. I hope to write for you an answer in the future. Meanwhile, please see the following work by Fujii: http://arxiv.org/abs/0901.2180v2

Comment: @Qmechanic : I've asked this question there too. However, I believe that I'll find an answer here, since this question is dictated by physical meaning (first of all).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because [crossposting is not allowed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/263383).